# math exponent function int attribute error

Tags: python, exponent

Everything I have seen shows that the proper syntax for running an exponent function from the math import is math.exp(some_num.exponent). When I attempt to run this format, the exponent is giving me an attribute error, saying it is not an int.
I have defined e = 29 and am trying to use e as the exponent.
Also n = 16637

I have also tried just using the ** operator. That allows me to use the 2 variable (mdic, e) to calculate, however when it runs the program I get an overflow error.

```
p = 127
q = 131
n = p * q
thetan = (p-1)*(q-1)
e = 29
if e < thetan:
    if math.gcd(e, thetan) == 1 and (e > 25):
        print("e = ", e)
print("gcd of ", e, " and thetan == ", math.gcd(e, thetan))
print("Public keys == ", e, ",", n)
for k in range(1,10):
    d = (k * thetan + 1)/ e
    if d / 1 == d // 1:
        print("d (private key) == ", d)
        print("k == ", k)
k = 6
d = (k * thetan + 1)/ e
print("e == ", e)
print("e*d -1 = ", (e*d -1))
m = {   50:'What is up?',
        51:'You are fast!',
        52:'All your trinkets belong to us.',
        53:'Someone on our team thinks someone on your team are in the same class.',
        54:'You are the weakest link.',
        55:'Encryption is fun;',
        56:'Spring is my favorite season',
        57:'Enjoy your morning beverage',
        58:'I am an early riser',
        59:'I am not an early riser',
        60:'Wake Tech is my school',
        61:'CSC 120 Computing Fundamentals',
        62:'Best wishes to you'

mdic = int(input("Enter an integer from the dictionary 'm' = {50 - 62}: "))
while mdic not in m:
    print("Input not a valid integer within the m dictionary.")
    mdic = int(input("Enter an integer from the dictionary 'm': "))

c = math.pow(mdic, e) % n
print("The encrypted text is: ", c)
m = math.pow(c, d) % n
print(m)
```

thank you for any guidance.
traceback for using the math.exp function protocol:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python Projects/Extra Credit/Extra Credit.py", line 47, in 
    c = math.exp(mdic.e) % n
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'e'

Comment: Could you add the full error traceback text to your post?

Comment: What is `mdic.e` supposed to be?

Comment: mdic is an input that correlates to a number in a dictionary 'm'. mdic should be between 50-62. This whole thing is for encryption. There is much more to the coding, but i hit a wall with the exponent issue

Comment: 29 raised to 16637 is rather large. Just saying.  int(input("Somestring")) gives you an int. What's the dictionary for? Are you trying to just report numbers you have already stored answers to?

Comment: Where did you read " math.exp(some_num.exponent)"?

Answer (score 1):

```
c = math.exp(mdic.e) % n
```

Here you're trying to access the `e` attribute of your `int`, `mdic`. Which raises the error.

You probably want:

```
c = math.pow(mdic, e) % n
```

Equivalently, let `pow` do the modular arithmetic for you.

```
c = math.pow(mdic, e, n)
```

`math.exp(x)` is for `e**x` - where `e` is Euler's constant

Comment: note that there's a third parameter to `pow` which would enable this to be written as `pow(e, mdic, n)`.  this uses [Modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) and is much faster/more efficient

Comment: @SamMason Thanks, added to the answer ^

Comment: I am looking for mdic to the power of e(29). Would that be c = math.pow(e, mdic) % n?

Comment: great help. Thank you. I will give it a go

Comment: that worked, but then my next portion of the code did not work: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python Projects/Extra Credit/Extra Credit.py", line 50, in <module>
    m = math.pow(c, d) % n
OverflowError: math range error

Comment: math.pow would not take n as an argument, so i left it outside and used % n